# Firebase Remote Config/Analytics setUserProperty condition does nothing

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We are using Firebase to setup different toggle-able features based of whether the app is currently pointing at Beta, Staging or Live so we can test gradually without fully going live with a feature.

We do this by setting 3 conditions inside Remote Config based on how the user property 'ios_environment' is set within the app.

[image]

Inside the Development version of the app we can switch between the environments easily which calls the following code to switch which condition the app is currently running under:

```
Analytics.setUserProperty(environment.rawValue, forName: "ios_environment")
```

Which sets it to either, "beta", "staging" or "live".

What happens in the app is for a particular Remote Config parameter it only ever decides to go with whatever the Default value is and never seems to pickup on the condition that is set:

[image]

So for the Parameter in the image above, we want it to be true only for the Beta environment but it only takes whatever the Default says.

I hope I've made my issue clear, it's hard to get what is wrong across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue that's recently fixed in v4.2.0. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios

Is your Firebase version early than that?

Comment: Should have know, needed to update the pod master repo in order for it to see the updated version of Firebase. Thanks for your help.